# Correlation plot between different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to find a correlation between multiple dataframe of different row size but same column size (column length=5).

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"A":[34,12,78,84,26,28,34], "B":[54,87,35,25,82,21,10], "C":[56,78,0,14,13,19,32], "D":[0,23,72,56,14,44,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34,1,21]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5],"A":[45,24,65,65,65], "B":[45,87,65,52,12], "C":[98,52,32,32,12], "D":[0,23,1,365,53], "E":[24,12,65,3,65]})
Z = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"A":[14,96,25,2,25,4], "B":[47,7,5,58,34,2], "C":[85,45,65,53,53,10], "D":[3,35,12,56,236,11], "E":[68,20,10,45,46,85]})

catted = pd.concat([d.set_index('t') for d in [X, Y, Z]], axis=1, keys=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
catted = catted.rename_axis(['Source', 'Column'], axis=1)

corrmat = catted.corr()

f, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmax=.8, square=True)
```

Now I want to create a correlation plot for the same dataframes but I changed the labels (t) as three class (all samples of dataframe X are from class 1; all samples of dataframe Y are from class 2, etc.) I want a correlation where each element of one dataframe will be correlated with other one (e.g., X-A will be correlated with Y-A,Y-B, Y-C, etc.),

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"A":[34,12,78,84,26,28,34], "B":[54,87,35,25,82,21,10], "C":[56,78,0,14,13,19,32], "D":[0,23,72,56,14,44,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34,1,21]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"t":[2,2,2,2,2],"A":[45,24,65,65,65], "B":[45,87,65,52,12], "C":[98,52,32,32,12], "D":[0,23,1,365,53], "E":[24,12,65,3,65]})
Z = pd.DataFrame({"t":[3,3,3,3,3,3],"A":[14,96,25,2,25,4], "B":[47,7,5,58,34,2], "C":[85,45,65,53,53,10], "D":[3,35,12,56,236,11], "E":[68,20,10,45,46,85]})

catted = pd.concat([d.set_index('t') for d in [X, Y, Z]], axis=1, keys=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
catted = catted.rename_axis(['Source', 'Column'], axis=1)

corrmat = catted.corr()

f, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmax=.8, square=True)
```

I got the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (60, 15), indices imply (18, 15)

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here and How to fix it?

Comment: X, Y and Z must have equal row size, you can't pd.concat different sizes

Comment: @MohamedAfify The first code works perfectly. concatenation was done by the column 't'. Bottom code the only difference is in the labels or 't' column.

Comment: oh, concat can't reindex the values with the repeated values. Make the class in a separate column instead of having it in index